# How to change header information of mail in Laravel?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, laravel-5.1

I am creating a simple contact us form using Laravel 5.1

```
public function sendMessage(){
    $data = [
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'subject' => Input::get('subject'),
        'body' => Input::get('body')
    ];
    Mail::send('emails.contact',$data, function($message) use($data){
        $message->from($data['email'], $data['name']);
        $message->to('smartrahat@gmail.com','Mohammed');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
    Session::flash('success_message','Mail sent successfully!');
    return redirect('contact');
}
```

Everything is working fine but the sender email address is not the one it get from the contact page. The email is sent from the address which I configure in `.env`

I want to have the email from the sender email address which he filled up contact form. Or, you can say I want to change the header information (only `from`, I can change other information).

Comment: Don't try to do this. Setting the submitter's address as the from address will almost guarantee that you will get SPF failures since you are forging the from address. The way to do it is to put your own address as the from address (so it will pass SPF), and put the submitter's address as a reply-to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Laravel will send the mail through the given smtp server. I guess the smtp server (e.g. google doing this) will not let you change your from address to another address then the account belongs to.

If you want to reply to this address directly in your email programm you can add `$message->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name']);`.

Comment: If I use other service except google smtp. Is it possible that, I can change the `from`? Please, tell me if there any other way I can change it.
This is not mandatory that I have to use smtp from google.

Comment: I assume it is not possible cause of authenticity of the email origin. I could send emails in name of Obama for e.g..

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I can do that with `Raw PHP code`. I just want to do it in Laravel way. So, asking for any other way if available.

Answer (score 0):

The `$message` variable inside the `Mail::send()` function is a SwiftMailer message instance. Therefore, you can work with headers just like the [SwiftMailer documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html) shows.  Just use `$message->getSwiftMessage()` to get and manipulate the headers.

Also, you absolutely can change the `From` header, but if you change it to a different domain, you'll have to deal with phishing warnings in the client. You can resolve that by setting up DKIM and SPF records, and you will need to have access to the DNS settings for the domain to do that.